# How to show popover if user only starts typing in input field?

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, uipopover

I have an input field, I want to show a popover only when user types into the field and I don't want to show the popover for the first time when the input field is empty.
I have written the following code but it shows the popover for the first time I click on it ! Any way to fix that?
here is the plnkr to show the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/d6WzzJYgDHlBmx1Pfb9L?p=preview

```
<input type="text"
    value="Click me!" 
    ng-model="value"
    popover-is-open="!!value"  
    uib-popover="This must be shown when use has typed value"  
    popover-trigger="focus"
    class="form-control">
```

Comment: Any solution ???

Comment: @khush I answered my own question below ... I don't remember actually ...

Answer (score 1):

I tried many other solutions, but this only worked for me.

I solved this by adding a new button with visibility hidden and binding popover with this button. On enter click of input I opened this popover manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code please, I changed click to change.

```
<div ng-controller="PopoverDemoCtrl">
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
    <input type="text"
    value="Click me!" 
    ng-model="value"
    popover-is-open="!!value"  
    uib-popover="This must be shown when use has typed value"  
    popover-trigger="change"
    class="form-control">

    <br />
    {{value}} -- {{!!value}}
</div>
```

Tell me,

thanks!

Comment: Wow ! Surprisingly that works pretty well, I didn't see that trigger anywhere ! How did you find it? But it doesn't close the popover when I outside click of input !

Comment: You are right, "type" work as "none", so is not correct. Is better to put none and check a way to disable the popover using "popover-is-open" or "popover-enable". Also I checked that popover-trigger="change" is working and popover-trigger="keyup" or mouseup or input or paste. Thats courious.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get my desired result, Here is how:

```
<input type="text"
    value="Click me!" 
    ng-model="value"
    popover-is-open="!!value && popUpOpen"  
    uib-popover="This must be shown when use has typed value"  
    popover-trigger="none"
    ng-blur="popUpOpen = false"
    ng-focus="popUpOpen = true"
    class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you found a soloution,this uses uib aswell and uses the trigger 'mouseclick'

```
<input vm.detectChange popover-append-to-body="true"  popover-placement="right" uib-popover-template="'popup.html'" popover-is-open="isOpen" popover-trigger="mouseclick" popover-title="Popup: ">
```

Comment: there is no `mouseclick` trigger I guess.